# Android Volley Library

Tags: android, api, django-models, android-volley

I want to know how to send volley login request if the login request url is

```
username:password http://‎login_url
```

in this format. It would be a great help if a sample code is available.
the purpose is to send login request to a django framework based website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show me what you did???

Comment: curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d  {"email":"someone@example.com","first_name":"FName","last_name":"Lname","password":"pass123"}' http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:1111/register_user/

this is how i should pass the values to the server.. can any one help me .. how is this possible using volley?

Answer (score 0):

first create a string request ->>

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

then, you should override the getParams() method!

```
@Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
                return params;
```

add the request to request queue!

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

three easy steps :)

feel free to ask any doubts

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// Tag used to cancel the request
String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

String url = "http:‎login_url";

ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pDialog.show();     

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //your response
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", "username");
                params.put("email", "abc@dffg.info");
                params.put("password", "password123");

                return params;
            }

        };

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
```